# which ubuntu release should I install on hp compaq dc5100mt?

Tags: system-installation

I have the hp compaq dc5100mt with the following specs: 1024x768, pentium 4, 3.0 ghz, 3.1 gb ram, 80gb hdd splitted in 60gb and 20gb. So I'd like to know which ubuntu release should I install on this PC

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I find out which version and derivative of Ubuntu is right for my hardware in terms of minimal system requirements?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/206407/how-do-i-find-out-which-version-and-derivative-of-ubuntu-is-right-for-my-hardwar)

Comment: Try Xubuntu 15.04 Vivid Vervet --- 32 bits

Answer (score 0):

The latest version of Ubuntu should be fine. See the system requirements site here:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements

It shows the minimum specs:

700 MHz processor (about Intel Celeron or better)
512 MiB RAM (system memory)
5 GB of hard-drive space (or USB stick, memory card or external drive but see LiveCD for an alternative approach)
VGA capable of 1024x768 screen resolution
Either a CD/DVD drive or a USB port for the installer media

Your information clearly exceeds these by a wide margin. There shouldn't be any problem with that. I would proceed with the install from here:

http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-ubuntu-desktop

Comment: Ubuntu will work but VERY slow. Lubuntu is preferable.